# a problem about using const char* to pass parameter

Tags: iphone, char, constants, objective-c++

I first store the 3 value into a pair of map like this:

```
void AddMenuAtlasTexture( int tag, const char* filename, const char* textureName )
{
 map<const char*, const char*> _item;
 _item.insert(pair<const char*, const char*>(filename, textureName));

 m_texturesToLoad.insert(pair<int, map<const char*, const char*> >(tag, _item));
};
```

then I pass the value to another function like this:

```
map<const char*, const char*>::iterator _content;
int _tag = (*m_texturesToLoadIterator).first;
_content = (*m_texturesToLoadIterator).second.begin();
AtlasManagerSingleton->AddAtlas((*_content).first, (*_content).second, _tag);
```

the "textureName" is an absolute path like this kind: "/Users/eddy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/5FDE0091-2E93-42FE-BB62-05A16429551D/Ranch.app/../Documents/shop_tex.png"

my problem is the first function can get the "textureName" right, but the second function "AddAtlas" can not get the path, the "(*_content).second" is NULL.

and the "AddAtlas" prototype is:

```
void AtlasManager :: AddAtlas( const char *a_configFile, const char *a_spriteName, int a_nKey )
```

I develop this in iPhone dev using XCode.

Comment: Show all the code you use to call `AddMenuAtlasTexture`.

Comment: Just a tip: you can use the -> operator instead of (*pointer).stuff. You can just do pointer->stuff.

Comment: Try using m_texturesToLoadIterator->second instead of (*m_texturesToLoadIterator).second  I think this might be an operator overload problem

Comment: thank you for your answers, but after I change to this "_content = m_texturesToLoadIterator->second.begin();", it still can't get the string.

Comment: Why you are not using std::string?

Answer (score 0):

- use `make_pair` instead of `pair<int, map<const char*, const char*> >`.
- use `->` instead of `*.`
- the texture loader is a map `int -> const char* -> const char*`. I don't see where you used the second index.

Probably this:

```
AtlasManagerSingleton->AddAtlas((*_content).first, (*_content).second, _tag)
```

Should be:

```
AtlasManagerSingleton->AddAtlas(_content->first, _content->second.begin()->second, _tag)
```